# Android - Call method from main class within JavaScriptInterface

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to android development and I'm trying to make a WebView that will allow me to launch the android camera app. How can I go about calling a method in the main class from with my JavaScriptInterface?

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1888;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
        mainWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        //mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/page.html");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }



    public void takePicture() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 


            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            }}

    }



package com.cargowise.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class JavaScriptInterface {



    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }


    public void takePic() {
        MainActivity.takePicture();
    }


    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have stored the context which you should be able to use to access your `MainActivity`.

Change this:

```
public void takePic() {
    MainActivity.takePicture();
}
```

To this:

```
public void takePic() {
    ((MainActivity)mContext).takePicture();
}
```

Note: you might want to add some type-checking or limit the type of the context that is given to a `MainActivity` to enforce correct behavior.

Comment: @cklab you are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of calling ((MainActivity)mContext).takePicture() is (probably) wrong, at least for me it failed. The reason is that the call will be *not* on the main/UI thread, but rather on some another thread.

Also, you MUST put the @JavascriptInterface annotation before each interface method.

The right way to place calls to main UI thread, which in turn will be able to do everything as usual on that thread, is this:

```
...inside JavaScriptInterface class

public void takePic() {
    ((MainActivity)mContext).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((MainActivity)mContext).takePicture();
        }
    });
}
```

In Kotlin it would look much simpler:

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun takePic() {
    (mContext as MainActivity).mainWebView?.post {
        (mContext as MainActivity).takePicture()
    }
}
```

Full example of integration of WebView with Android backend, with calls bak and forth between JS and Android, is here: https://github.com/latitov/Android_WebViewApp_FullScreen